# How do i make a cfg Control the Batch File?

Tags: file, batch-file, config

I wanna Make a cfg file to Take Control of the Batch File Like

```
StartBatchFile=True
UseModFolder=False
```

But... I don't Know how to make it Work, Could You Help Me?

Comment: Do you need to know how to read in the contents of the file (read `for /?`), or compare the values of variables (read `if /?`)?

Comment: Yes. I want it.